# pro*c/c++ using fetch in nested loop - SQL

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

How to write an ORACLE pro*C/C++ dynamic SQL query (method 4)

I want to perform a multiple fetch on a single sql statement.

The first fetch will just count the number of rows (elements).

Knowing this, I will then reset the cursor to the first row and fetch the values for each row.

I will be glad if someone can provide some guidance and an example code on how to do this.

Comment: mention your database name like SQL SERVER,ORACLE, MY SQL etc

Comment: The database is ORACLE.  Thank you.

Comment: "The first fetch will just count the number of rows (elements).

Knowing this, I will then reset the cursor to the first row and fetch the values for each row."
Why would you do that? You could just fetch until there is data to be fetched. Why would you want to fetch just the number of results and why wouldn't you just split this in 2 separate queries, considering 2 queries will be simpler and actually faster than rewinding a cursor, yet slower than a single query just fetching all the results. Why do you need it to be dynamic in that sense?